# I want to use session variable value in javascript

Tags: php

Here I want to use session variable's value in javascript function. I tried

```
var varname = '<?php echo $_SESSION["variable_name"]; ?>';
```

But it doesn't pass the value it shows the string

### so how can i use session variable of php inside the javascript.

Actually I want to check captcha code in java script side.
Here i already make contactus.php file where I generat captcha value from rand function. Then i store this value in session variable. Here I already made validation.js file to validate contact us form fields so in same file i want to validate captha so for that I  has been trying below code but its not working        .

```
var cap = document.frm.captcha.value;
var ca = '<?= addslashes($_SESSION["code"]); ?>';
alert (cap); //ITs shows my entered value perfectly
alert (ca); //but it doesn't show generated captcha value. it simply print '<?= addslashes($_SESSION["code"]); ?>'//

if(cap!=ca)
{
    alert("Insert correct captcha code");
    document.frm.captcha.focus();
    return false;
}
```

I checked session variable value it works fine on php page but dosen;t work on javascript page.

Comment: If the page where this code is put is a .php page and IF your hoster support php programming it should work. AND at the begin of the page you need to use the session_start();

Comment: `echo "<script type='javascript'>var username=\"$_SESSION[variable_name]\"</script>"; `

Comment: @LauriElias Of course he does unless it's a number or `true`, `false` or `null`?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var varname = <?php echo $_SESSION["variable_name"]; ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Have you ever try this code in your project? without quotes it stops whole java script.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php echo "var variable = '". $_SESSION['variable']."';" ?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The file which contains this code must be named `.php` and has to be a `session_start();` at the beginning of the PHP-File.

Then this code should work.

Comment: "*The file which contains this code must be named .php*" - not nessesary. As long as the webserver is setup to run the document through the PHP parser the extension can be anything.

Comment: That's correct, but show me one webserver that is configured like this. I don't think that user3136794 got a webserver configured like this.

Comment: @h2ooooooo if it's a standard server TRY to put php code inside .html and see the result :)

Comment: @MarcelBalzer Many webservers also come with default extensions of `.php3`, `.php4`, `.php5`, `.phps` etc.

Comment: Yes, but nearly every webserver parses .php with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There is several posibilities, why your code isn`t working.

1. There is an error in variable (Eg unescaped quote)
2. Code is outside of Javascript code.
3. Session is not started in the moment of getting variable

For fixing this 3 errors you need to use following code -

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var varname = '<?= addslashes($_SESSION['variable_name']); ?>';
</script>
```

If in your session variable is not a string or number you need to pack it to the JSON object. In this case you can just make following:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var varname = <?= json_encode($_SESSION['variable_name']); ?>;
</script>
```

Last variant of code will make all types of variable are frendly to JS. Also string.

For example with json_encode from `asd'd"sa` string you will get `"asd'd\"sa"` string.

**UPD:**
If you use this file like JS file like follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../path/to/file.php"></script>
```

for correct work you need to use following code.

```
<?php 
session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
?>
var varname = '<?= addslashes($_SESSION['variable_name']); ?>';
```